# Android using indexOf

Tags: java, android, string

I have this, `tweet.title` is a string that is equals to `I love burgers.`

```
        CharSequence i = tweet.title.indexOf(Integer.valueOf("I"));

        SpannableString WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(i);        
        WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 7, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        holder.txtTitle.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

Now I get this error from it `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to CharSequence`

I wanna find the `I` in the string.

Comment: Please check the answer I provided below. There was an error in your code that I didn't spot earlier. The code I provided below now works as you'd expect. That is, it returns the "I".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Code (tested and works)

```
CharSequence i = tweet.title.indexOf(Integer.valueOf("I"));
```

should be

```
int index = tweet.title.indexOf("I"); // find int position of "I"

// set to be the String of where "I" is to plus 1 of that position
CharSequence i = tweet.title.substring(index, index + 1);

// Alternative to substring, you could use charAt, which returns a char
CharSequence i = Character.toString(tweet.title.charAt(index));
```

---

#### Explanation

`indexOf(String)` returns the `int` *position* of where that `String` is. 

You gave `Integer.valueOf("I")` as the `String` to `indexOf(String)`.

`Integer.valueOf(String)` converts a `String` to an `Integer`. Why would you give the `indexOf(String)` an `Integer` and why would you try to convert `"I"` to an `Integer`?

What you meant to do was this: `CharSequence i = tweet.title.indexOf("I");` but that is also wrong because it will return an `int` (position in the `String`), hence the mismatch error.

You need to find the position of `"I"` in the `tweet.title`, so that's `tweet.title.indexOf("I")`. Then set the `CharSequence` to be `tweet.title` at that position up until that position +1 (so that you get just the one character `I`).

Comment: Voted up. Good explanation.

Answer (score 4):

String.indexOf returns an int not a CharSequence. Also, you can't get the index of the I using Integer.valueOf().

```
    int i = tweet.title.indexOf("I");
```

If you want to just get the "I" back do this:

```
    int i = tweet.title.indexOf("I");
    String s = tweet.title.substring(i, i + 1);
```

Edited: I fixed a couple of bugs in this code.

Answer (score 3):

`String.contains()` which checks if the string contains a specified sequence of char values
`String.indexOf()` which returns the index within the string of the first occurence of the specified character or substring (there are 4 variations of this method)

Answer (score 1):

You can work with String because it implements the CharSequence interface. See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html).

Because you want just one letter you can get the char at the index and make a String out of it:

```
    int i = tweet.title.indexOf("I");
    String letter = Character.toString(tweet.title.charAt(i));

    SpannableString wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(letter);        
    wordtoSpan.setSpan(
            new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 7, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

If you wanna get more chars of your String you can use the [String.subString(int beginIndex, int endIndex)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method.

F.e: you wanna get "burgers":

```
    int i = tweet.title.indexOf("b");
    String sub = title.subString(i, i + 6);
    SpannableString wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(sub);        
    wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 7, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```